# Changing Python version in Xubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, xubuntu

I am in the processing learning python. I was previously learning in Python. I used version 3. Today, I installed Xubuntu 13.04. I am a very new Xubuntu user. The os had two versions pre installed. 2.7.4 and 3.3. When I type python in the console, v2.7.4 opens up. How do I change that to v3.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run Python 3, use the `python3` command. To set Python 3 as default, add a symlink to `/usr/local/bin` as root:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

After doing that, you can still execute Python 2 with `python2` or `python2.7`.

Answer (score 1):

Type python3 instead of simply python. Python runs 2.x, whereas python3 runs 3.x

Answer (score 0):

The Debian way typically involves using `update-alternatives`

So for Python:

`sudo update-alternatives --config python`